# How does "make my" fit here if subject is still unmarried?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

In *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), J.J complains to Officer Kello about Sidney's rude behavoir towards J.J, sister's Susan, who is unmarried:

> J.J: Behind my back he was trying to **make my** sister.

How does "make my" fit here if subject is still unmarried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a standard idiom.

I guess it is a euphemism, typical of the social context of the 1950s. You can't understand the meaning from the words, you have to "read between the lines".

Comment: It's perfectly standard, if somewhat vulgar.

Answer (score 1):

It means he tried to have sex with his sister.

Comment: But **make someone** used for married woman.

Comment: @MackRodney Yes. It can be used for any person